# Could not connect to mysql8 after installation in laragon

Tags: mysql, laragon

I copy mysql 8.0.26 zip file and copied to laragon bin file

I added my.ini in the mysql-version with following congiuration

```
myisam_sort_buffer_size=64M
thread_cache_size=8
skip-grant-tables=1
secure-file-priv=""
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp=1
datadir= "D:/laragon_new/data/mysql-8"
default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password


[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet=512M

[mysql]
user=root
password=
```

I added the mysqlbin path toe windows environment

when I type mysql -u root -p

prompts password I have not set

I tried `mysqld -skip-grant-tables -skip-networking`

to reset the password still get access denied

I cannot  connect to mysql to reset the password

`mysqladmin -u root password 123`

I tried this and did not work

I am not able to login from phpmyadmin

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)\
```

```
2021-09-21T20:48:27.427381Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] D:\laragon_new\bin\mysql\mysql-8.0.26-winx64\bin\mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.26'  socket: ''  port: 0  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2021-09-21T20:48:27.428490Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010131] [Server] TCP/IP, --shared-memory, or --named-pipe should be configured on NT OS
2021-09-21T20:48:27.429135Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2021-09-21T20:48:28.199109Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013183] [InnoDB] Assertion failure: trx0sys.cc:645:UT_LIST_GET_LEN(trx_sys->mysql_trx_list) == 0 thread 16696
```

Why the port is 0? where to change it

Comment: Have you been able to solve that? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Yes Solved. Dont use Laragon Mysql Installer. Mysql8 version generate the root password that need to be captured. Install mysql8 manually  from terminal by downloading